# Is it possible to add extra indentation to a line in a foldable Yaml text block without breaking the folding?

Tags: yaml

Consider the following Yaml that specifies a fixed indentation of two spaces:

```
yaml: >-2
  First line
  will fold.

  Second line
  should fold
  as well.
```

Which, de-serializes to:

```
{
  "yaml": "First line will fold.\nSecond line should fold as well."
}
```

The result text is folded as expected. There are two separate lines only (the newline character can be found between the "fold." and the "Second" words).

Now, if some extra blank spaces are added before the "Second" word, the folding logic breaks. Let's assume this extra space is part of the text itself, not part of the Yaml indentation (as the latter was fixed to two blank spaces):

```
yaml: >-2
  First line
  will fold.

       Second line
  should fold
  as well.
```

This de-serializes to:

```
{
  "yaml": "First line will fold.\n\n     Second line\nshould fold as well."
}
```

Now, three separate lines are generated, and the first one contains two consecutive newline characters, which is unexpected.

Is it possible to add some extra spacing indentation to Yaml text blocks (indentation that is part of the text data, not part of the Yaml indentation), without breaking the folding logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML behaves [as specified](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761056):

> Folded newlines are preserved for "more indented" and blank lines

You can use a quoted scalar instead, which also does line folding but handles indentation differently:

```yaml
yaml:
 "First line
  will fold.

  \     Second line
  should fold
  as well."
```

Here, you escape the first space that should be content since leading space is completely stripped. This evaluates to

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
--- 
!!map {
  ? !!str "yaml"
  : !!str "First line will fold.\n     Second line should fold as well."
}
```